# How to convert empty string to null for all column in Talend

Tags: string, null, talend

I have a big mapping of many columns from a CSV file in my Talend job.

The point is CSV doesn't support `NULL` and switch all null to empty string `""`.

How can I convert every empty string value in every columns to `NULL` ?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have "CSV options" with "text enclosure" checked in the advanced options of tFileOutputDelimited ?

Comment: @Corentin I yes use the text enclosure as this CSV ship some multi-lines fields. But with or without CSV option it's the same : `null` is changed as `""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a way that don't imply to map everything one by one.

The trick is to use [tConvertType](https://help.talend.com/reader/q23BCE3W4MjloHD1RvMJ4A/GDoeGgb~qKpyQ_84gB37WQ)
With the `Auto Cast` and the `Set empty values to Null before converting` option enable :

[image: tConvertType configuration]

This'll make the empty string `""` to `NULL` conversion for all fields :

[image: job convert empty string to null]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use tReplace component, it looks like what you need.

But in case it won't help with empty strings - you always can do like this: 
[image]

Comment: Yes, that was what I found first, but as I have a few *hundred* of col to map, it's just no use :/